# Why can't you bend your index finger after your nervus medianus gets injured?

Tags: muscle, anatomy, nerves

When you get a proximal injury of your nervus medianus, you get the symptom called "The hand of benediction".

[image]

So among other things, you can not bend your index finger (because your mm. flexor digit. sup. and prof. are not innervated).

But I also have read that there are those small hand muscles called musculi interossei. And they are supposed to be able to bend your fingers in the articulationes metacarpophalangeales (Metacarpophalangeal joint = MCP). And also they are innervated by the nervus ulnaris - not the nervus medianus.

So why can't patients bend their fingers at least at the MCP joints?

I discussed that with my peers and our theory is, that the book is wrong about the action of the muscle. We think that the best explanation is that the musculi interossei just abduct the fingers. Some sources only list that action, so it sounds reasonable. But some others (including the main book we are all learning with) claim that there is also a flexion in the MCP joint.

Thank you for your help